# How can I disable a collection of checkboxes and textareas upon checking a different checkbox?

Tags: html, jquery

I have an HTML table with each row containing a series of inputs (checkboxes and textareas) to be filled in by the user. I want to make it so that if the first checkbox in the row is checked, the other inputs in that row are disabled. I only really know rudimentary HTML and have no experience with JavaScript so am struggling with this problem.

I can get it to work for the first input by using a snippet from someone else's post that uses `getElementById`, but I want multiple inputs to be disabled (see below, apologies for formatting).

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align: center;">
<input name="aaa" onchange="Disable(this.checked)" type="checkbox" />
</td>
<script>
function Disable(_checked) {document.getElementById('bbb').disabled = _checked ? true : 
false;}
</script>
<td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align: center;"><input id="bbb" name="bbb" 
type="checkbox" /></td>
```

I guess I could just use several scripts using this to make it work for all of the inputs in a row, but I'm sure it could be shortened. I've tried giving the inputs a class name and using `getElementsByClassName` but can't get it to work, perhaps because I'm trying to disable two different types of input at once?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job without the need for defining any IDs:

```js
document.body.onclick = ev => {
  if (ev.target.type == "checkbox")
    ev.target.closest("div")
    .querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox],textarea")
    .forEach(el => el == ev.target || (el.disabled = ev.target.checked))
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label><input name="aaa" type="checkbox">AAA</label>
  <br>
  <label><input name="bbb" type="checkbox">BBB</label>
  <br>
  <label><input name="ccc" type="checkbox">CCC</label>
  <br><textarea>texarea one</textarea>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <label><input name="aaa" type="checkbox">AAA</label>
  <br>
  <label><input name="bbb" type="checkbox">BBB</label>
  <br>
  <label><input name="ccc" type="checkbox">CCC</label>
  <br><textarea>texarea two</textarea>
</div>
```

In this simplified snippet the `<div>`s play the role of table rows (`<tr>`), so in your page you will need to replace the selector "div" with "tr".

I guess the line

```
.forEach(el => el == ev.target || (el.disabled = ev.target.checked))
}
```

deserves some further explanation. The forEach-loop goes through all the checkbox and textarea elements that exist in the same div as the clicked checkbox. Then, depending on whether the current element `el` is identical with the clicked checkbox (`ev.target`) either nothing happens, or in case `el` is *not* the clicked element then the `el`'s display-property is set to the checked-state of the clicked checkbox. I am exploiting the fact that JavaScript treats expressions with an "or" (`||`) operator in a *lazy* way: if the condition before the "or" operator is true then the second expression (after the "or") is completely irrelevant and will not even be evaluated any more.

Comment: Thanks for this - is it possible for a modified version of this to work in which CCC is a textarea, so that it is disabled along with BBB upon checking AAA?

Comment: Well, the textarea will already be disabled alongside all other input elements in the same div (in your case you would probably work with "tr"s instead). If you want, you can add a label around the textarea and call it "ccc". ;-)